# How do I automate Google Sheets to pick a word per day from a column of 365 words, and update the word in a specific cell every 24 hours

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a database with 365 random words in column "A" in Google Sheets spreadsheet. In another column, that I have called "word of the day", in the second row, I would like Google to automatically input, every 24 hours, a word from the list in column "A". Ideally, I would like the update to happen in the order in which I have the words in column "A". For example, let's say that the three first words in the list in column "A" are "fox", "lion" and "sheep". The first day, for 24 hours, I would like the word "fox" to be the one that shows in the "word of the day" cell. THe second day, I would like the word "lion" to show instead of the word "fox", in the exact same cell where "fox" was being shown. The third, I would like the word "sheep" to replace" the word "lion". And so on, for the rest of the year, with the 365 words.

This is because later on I am trying to link my website to the cell with the word of the day, so that the word is published automatically.

I have tried doing it by recording a macro using the SUBSTITUTE formula, and then scheduling it to run every 24 hours using the Apps Script tool. But all I get is that even though the first word changes to the second word in the row, then it doesn't keep going down the list. It's like I don't know how to tell Google to somehow record that it has to keep going down the list, once every 24 hours.

Comment: Is the word chosen at random from the list, or is the next days word the next word on the list?  So for example on day 24 its the work in row 24 and on day 25 its row 25?

Comment: The word is not chosen at random. As you said in your example, on day 24 I need the word from row 24, on day 25th the word from row 25 and so on. Thank you for your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wordaday() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const sr = 1;
  const ws = sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat();
  const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (ws.length - 1));
  //Logger.log(ws[idx]);
  return ws[idx];
}

function createWordADayTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "wordaday").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("wordaday").timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(6).create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do I just copy and paste this on Apps Scripts? I'm also not sure about if I still have to use the SUBSTITUTE formula in Excel to record the Macro. And would I also need to add an activator in Apps Scripts?

Comment: This is what is what my macros.gs standard register shows, but I'm unsure about how to paste the code you gave me: function {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=SUBSTITUTE(A3;A3;A4)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C4').activate();
};

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to calculate the day of the year and get the word from that row.  However, I add 1 to account for headers.

```
function wordOfTheDay() {
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let date = new Date();
  date =  Math.floor((date - new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
  let word = sheet.getRange(date+1,1).getValue();
  sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(word)
}
```

And here is an example of getting a random word each day.  Once a word has been picked it is eliminated from the list by placing the word "used" next to it so its not used again.  On Jan 1 column B of Sheet1 needs to be cleared.

```
function randomWord() {
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let words = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  words.shift();  // remove headers
  let unused = words.filter( row => row[1] === "" );
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random()*unused.length);
  let word = unused[index][0];
  index = words.findIndex( row => row[0] === word );
  sheet.getRange(index+2,2).setValue("used");
  sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(word);
}
```